# Can't Mount exFat partition with Linux (exFat is installed)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mount, data-recovery, exfat

I am running Linux on an external SSD.
I am trying to mount an exFat partition which is on the internal hard drive. ( MS Windows is installed on an NTFS partition on the internal drive. )

exFat is already installed ( `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`).

`sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sda4 /media/me/restored`
returns
`FUSE exfat 1.2.8
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.`

`sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/me/restored`
returns
`mount: /media/me/restored: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
 on /dev/sda4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

`lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,SIZE,FSTYPE`
returns

```
NAME   LABEL        SIZE FSTYPE
sda               931.5G isw_raid_member
├─sda1 SYSTEM_DRV   260M vfat
├─sda2               16M isw_raid_member
├─sda3 Windows    246.7G ntfs
├─sda4            683.6G isw_raid_member
└─sda5 WINRE_DRV  998.5M ntfs
sdb               465.8G 
├─sdb1              512M vfat
├─sdb2             83.7G ext4
└─sdb4 SSD-D      381.6G exfat
```

sda3 is the internal Windows partition.
sda4 is the internal exFat partition, created with diskmgmt.msc (in Windows).

Comment: To gather a little more info, please post the results of `lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,SIZE,FSTYPE` (add to your question). I'm mostly interested in the FSTYPE field.

Comment: Done.  I've never seen isw_raid_member before...

Comment: Very interesting. Reboot into Windows and post a picture of the **Disk Manager** output.

Comment: I thought [this link helped you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199473/how-to-change-ownership-of-files-recovered-by-scalpel-onto-exfat-partition/1199504#1199504). It is actually answering another question, but the instructions how to mount an exfat partition are relevant for you. I thought we solved the problem, but it seems the problem popped up again, now with the internal drive. What did you do to change the file system in `/dev/sda4`?

Comment: The directory exists.  I'm going to reboot into Windows and post the Disk Manager output.

Comment: Could the problem be that Windows was [semi]hibernated (maybe using Fast Startup), so that things you were doing with Linux were overwritten by Windows when booted again? Corruption can go the other way too: What you do in Linux can overwrite what should be used by Windows to restore the [semi]hibernated state.

Comment: @sudodus - That was with an external drive via USB.  This is about the internal drive.

Comment: The problem is gone.  I deleted the exFat partition in Windows, and recreated it.  I was going through the options to see if I could set something differently, and there's nothing to set.  --- Weird.  I had just made that partition larger a few minutes before - I reduced the size of the Windows partition, deleted the exFat partition, and then remade the exFat partition using all the space.  That partition was never used, so there couldn't have been any data in it.

Comment: That partition is no longer an isw_raid_member, but the other two still are.  lsblk now reports the partition as exFat.

Comment: @sudodus -- My previous question you were responding to was about an external drive, not the internal drive this post is about.

Comment: Does this mean that you have solved the problem (or at least that the problem has disappeared), now that lsblk reports the partition as `exfat`?

Comment: It has disappeared.  lsblk now shows that as an exFat partition, and those other two Windows partitions still show as isw_raid_member (which I don't think they really are).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102776/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jasonf4).

Comment: Maybe when I extended the exFat partition, it kept some definition bits from the Windows partition, and that got cleared when I deleted are recreated the partition?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by deleting the exFat partition in Windows, and recreating it (with diskmgmnt.msc).  This partition was originally created in Windows earlier today, exactly the same way, so I don't know how this solved the problem.

`lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,SIZE,FSTYPE`
now returns
`NAME   LABEL         SIZE FSTYPE
 sda                931.5G isw_raid_member
 ├─sda1 SYSTEM_DRV    260M vfat
 ├─sda2                16M isw_raid_member
 ├─sda3 Windows     246.7G ntfs
 ├─sda4 RestoredWin 683.6G exfat
 └─sda5 WINRE_DRV   998.5M ntfs
 sdb                465.8G 
 ├─sdb1               512M vfat
 ├─sdb2              83.7G ext4
 └─sdb4 SSD-D       381.6G exfat`

Comment: It appears that by deleting and recreating the partition I accomplished the same thing as "sudo dmraid -rE /dev/sda" - which clears an incorrect indication of Raid storage that Winodows wrote.